# Cannot pass condition as boolean in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, boolean, components

I want to try to pass a condition in a string clause because these parameters are in the target component:

***source.component:***

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  condition: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.condition = !"element.id === 2";
  }
}
```

However, I cannot use this condition in the target component:

***target.component:***

```
@Input() condition;


<button *ngIf="!condition" mat-menu-item (click)="openDialog(element)">Edit</button>
```

Here is the demo for this problem:

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-demo-n6gmuz?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html)**

Why I do not add these parameters manually to the target component is that; it is a reusable component and the conditions may be different for another component. So, how can I pass the condition from another component?

just have a look at

```
<button *ngIf="element.id % 2 === 0" mat-menu-item (click)="openDialog(element)">Edit</button>
```

Instead of setting `*ngIf="element.id % 2 === 0`, I need to pass `element.id % 2 === 0` part from another component e.g. condition: `'element.id % 2 === 0'`. Then I need to get that option via `@Input` in this component. But I receive it as string and when I convert it it always returns true :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, trying to pass the condition as a string is a bad approach. You should try to pass a function instead.

TS:

```
condition: (number) => boolean;

ngOnInit() {
  this.condition = id => id % 2 === 0;
}
```

HTML of target

```
<button *ngIf="!condition(element.id)" mat-menu-item (click)="openDialog(element)">Edit</button>
```

Check [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-demo-sh1ykf?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html)

**Update:**

For multiple optional conditions, better would be to implement `OnChanges`

TS:

```
options: Options[];

ngOnInit() {

  this.options = [
    { id: 1, isTest: false },
    { id: 2, isTest: true },
    { id: 8, isTest: true }
  ];
}
```

TS of target:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
  if (changes.options) {
    this.options.forEach(option => {
      const element = this.database.find(data=>data.id === option.id);
      if (element) element.isTest = option.isTest
    })
  }
}
```

HTML of target

```
<button *ngIf="element.isTest" mat-menu-item (click)="openDialog(element)">Edit</button>
```

See [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-demo-cnbun1?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it seems to be good idea, you are right. Your approach is really good, but there is just a little problem. If I use a class or interface for the condition, I cannot pass the value. I updated your demo and you can see the difference in **METHOD I** and **METHOD II**. The only difference is just passing the condition in an interface. How can I make the METHOD II work? Here is the **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-demo-qn7etz?file=app/table-basic-example.html)**

Comment: You can pass any data to the function and implement your condition logic. The Method II shown is an array and not a condition. I could not understand what you need with Method II. Can you explain the use of Method II

Comment: Actually I have a button array and I need to set a specific condition for each button. for this reason I have to pass the condition as a parameter of the array. So, could it be possible to pass the condition as in METHOD II approach? And how?

Comment: Each button will get a separate condition. Pass the individual element item to the condition. I can help with condition if you show how you have implemented your buttons.

Comment: Thanks, but you don't need the real state, because I have already added everything to the DEMO in my previous comment. Just look at the lines marked as //Method II and uncomment it on the `table-basic-example.html` file. Then make necessary test on that demo. Thanks a lot in advance for your kind helps.

Comment: As per my understanding, I find you need to pass condition as a singleton, so change, the condition to `options[0].condition(element.isTest)`. Find the working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-demo-cnbun1?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228835/discussion-between-t-sunil-rao-and-natalia).

Comment: I realized that when I add new options to 'this.options', and does not set  `condition` property it throws error. I think I can fix it by setting a default value `true` for this condition method. How could I do this? Because there are many option in the options array and I do not want to add a condition property to all of them. Any idea?

Comment: Best would be to implement OnChanges and monitor changes on both conditions and options and update the datasource on every change. Will update the stackblitz in a while

Comment: But I think a better approach is to make the condition option as optional in order not affect the currently present items. What about returning true as default for the condition function?

Comment: Maybe instead of returning default value, we can check first if the option has condition variable and if not omit its as true.

Comment: Please check the updated Stackbliz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-demo-cnbun1?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts

Comment: Many thanks for your useful helps. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your condition as a function in your `target` component like this.

target.component:

```
condition: any;
ngOnInit(){
   this.condition = (id: any): boolean => {
      return id !== 2;
   }
}
```

and in your `target.component`

```
<button *ngIf="condition(element.id)" mat-menu-item (click)="openDialog(element)">Edit</button>
```

[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-demo-9ivepu?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html)

So in this implementation you will make your code more secure. Because javascript `eval` is not recommended because `eval` can execute any `js` code in it. So hackers can hit that area. So you can implement above solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping, but it does not work when I tried to apply on stackblitz. Could you please try to apply it on the demo? Maybe I missed some points.

Comment: @Natalia please check my updated answer. I have updated my solution

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to understand how angular resolves expression as string,

it internally uses `eval('expression as string')`

I did changed the on init as following

**Source Component :**

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  condition: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.condition = "eval('!(element.id === 2)')";
  }
}
```

here's the working link :
[Working Demo link](https://angular-mat-table-demo-ygagp7.stackblitz.io)

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot make your demo work. Could you check it please?

Comment: I think the problem with my code is related to passing the condition in an array. So, could you please have a look at this **[NEW DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-demo-nwngr8?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html)**? In this demo the Method I is working like a charm, but when converting the parameter by passing in an array, Methıd II is not working. How can I make it work in this  **[NEW DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-demo-nwngr8?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html)**?

Comment: @Natalia Here's the new link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-demo-nggw8v

Comment: You're welcome. I would be happy if you upvote so that I can enough reputation for some action. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval`

```js
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  condition: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.condition = "eval('!(element.id === 2'))";
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem with my code is related to passing the condition in an array. So, could you please have a look at this **[NEW DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-demo-nwngr8?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html)**? In this demo the Method I is working like a charm, but when converting the parameter by passing in an array, Methıd II is not working. How can I make it work in this  **[NEW DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-demo-nwngr8?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html)**?